# How to make my site valid using SSL?

Tags: security, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a website that is on a dedicated server with a dedicated IP and has a SSL Certificate installed (and is valid).

When I go to my website and enter https instead of http my site only partially loads, because google chrome says my site has some non-secure data.

My site does not do anything with usernames, passwords, logins, etc (YET).
What would cause this to happen, and how do I fix this?

**EDIT**
I don't think you will have to, but if you do need to know the URL it is:
https://www.thexcodec.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because you are mixing content served over HTTP and HTTPS.

HTTPS is an all or nothing scheme. As soon as you include any content over plain HTTP, whether javascript, css, images or anything else, you have lost the confidence that the page contains only trusted content from a trusted source. Ensure you only request other resources over HTTPS.

I can see that you pull in resources over HTTP from Google maps. you will need to switch those to HTTPS.

Comment: I am very new to this SSL stuff. Thank you.